# I wanted to fix my hard drive bad sectors but it keep saying I/O error inreturn

Tags: debian, partition, windows, badblocks, parrotsec

So, I was messing up the Windows paging value and accidentally set it to 30Gb and made my PC blue screen. Then I can no longer boot into Windows or GNU/Linux (I have dual boot setup). Luckily I still have the USB bootable for Parrot OS so I use live mode to help me recover but until now I haven't got anything successful.

What I have done:

- Download Windows iso for repair PC options but can't access my C drive because it keeps saying I/O error.
- Check for bad blocks using `badblocks` command in the terminal and most sectors/blocks are broken.

What I'm going to do:

- Use S.M.A.R.T or `ddrescue` to check my drive.

I can't access my main drive and sometimes the partition just disappears on the list from `fdisk -l`. I can boot into Windows installation but I can't `chkdsk` the drive because I/O error. So, I need a way to fix or at least can get my important files back.

Comment: Seems to be mechanical failure.

Comment: any ideas to pick up the data back or its gone forever?

Comment: It depends on how valuable your data is to you. You can hand your drive over to a data recovery professional, pay them well, and hope they are able to recover at least some of your data. Otherwise, consider the data gone forever. `ddrescue` might work but keep in mind that if your drive has a mechanical failure, every attempt to read it increases the risk of further damage. That's why it boils down to how valuable your data is to you.

Comment: Erroneous tryout to fix may break it even more. If content is important, I would hand it over to a professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I bought a new hard drive for now and I will send the old one to data recovery specialist. Thanks for the help everyone :)